# How to compile tikz files into article?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I've been using forest to make logical proof tree. For my project I need to compile them all into a large file and add commentary which does not belong in the tree. Any advice on how to do that would be much appreciated.

For reference, the code looks like this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\def\shoe{$\supset$}
\def\nee{$\mathord{\sim}$}
\def\nein{$\neg$}
\def\lub{$\lor$}

\begin{document}
  \forestset{
    ass/.append style={
      before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      no edge
    },
  }
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
      align=center,
    },
[\nee \exists (D^1 \& C^1), ass, name=n1
    [\nee C^1 f, ass, name=n2
        [\nee D^1 f, ass, name=n3
            [\forall \nee (D^1 \& C^1), ass, name=n4
                [\nee (D^1 f \& C^1 f), ass, name=n5
                    [\nee D^1 f, name=n6]
                    [\nee C^1 f]
                    ]]]]]                ]
    \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
      \node [xshift=-50pt, anchor=east] at (n\i -| n1) {\i.};
    \foreach \i/\j in {1/{(premise)}, 2/{(premise)}, 3/{(negated conclusion)}, 4/{(1, QE)}, 5/{(4, UQ)}, 6/{(5, \nee \&)}}
      \node [xshift=50pt, anchor=west] at (n\i -| n1) {\j};
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that I have an experimental package now which should, hopefully, make the trees a lot easier.

Comment: Your code does not compile, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, @cfr ! I saw that but your code was still incredibly helpful and I'm finished transcribing my jungle into Latex. Now I just need to know how to make it all into one big file

Comment: I meant more if you need to draw more of these again: it should be easier. (If the package works, which it may well not.)

Answer (score 3):

You can just include the trees as you would any other diagram: either directly in the middle of the text or as figures. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\def\shoe{\ensuremath{\supset}}
\def\nee{\ensuremath{\sim}}
\def\nein{\ensuremath{\neg}}
\def\lub{\ensuremath{\lor}}
  \forestset{
    ass/.append style={
      before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      no edge
    },
  }

\begin{document}

  Here is some text referring to figure \ref{fig:tree}.
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
      \begin{forest}
        for tree={
          parent anchor=south,
          child anchor=north,
          align=center,
          math content
        },
    [\nee \exists (D^1 \& C^1), ass, name=n1
        [\nee C^1 f, ass, name=n2
            [\nee D^1 f, ass, name=n3
                [\forall \nee (D^1 \& C^1), ass, name=n4
                    [\nee (D^1 f \& C^1 f), ass, name=n5
                        [\nee D^1 f, name=n6]
                        [\nee C^1 f]
                        ]]]]]                ]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
          \node [xshift=-50pt, anchor=east] at (n\i -| n1) {\i.};
        \foreach \i/\j in {1/{(premise)}, 2/{(premise)}, 3/{(negated conclusion)}, 4/{(1, QE)}, 5/{(4, UQ)}, 6/{(5, \nee \&)}}
          \node [xshift=50pt, anchor=west] at (n\i -| n1) {\j};
      \end{forest}
    \caption{A tree}
    \label{fig:tree}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that I had to add `math content` to get this to compile at all so the output is not really ideal but it demonstrates how to put it into an ordinary `article`. If you don't want the trees to move around (float), just don't use the `figure` environment and put them in the appropriate places as you wish in the text.

[image: tree as figure]

Alternatively, you can say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest,standalone}

\def\shoe{\ensuremath{\supset}}
\def\nee{\ensuremath{\sim}}
\def\nein{\ensuremath{\neg}}
\def\lub{\ensuremath{\lor}}
  \forestset{
    ass/.append style={
      before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      no edge
    },
  }

\begin{document}

Some text and now a tree:
\input{tree1}% if tree1.tex is the first tree
\begin{figure}
  \input{tree2}
  \caption{Tree 2}\label{fig:tree2}
\end{figure}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

And then you don't have to touch your existing tree files or mess around copy-pasting.

## EDIT

Here is proper example using the second method. (Note that one tree is in a `figure` environment and one is not. This is just for illustration: I'm not recommending this. If you do mix them, you should use `capt-of` or `caption` to caption to label the non-floating trees consistently.)

Suppose that `tree1.tex` contains:

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
  \usepackage{prooftrees}
  \standaloneenv{forest}
  \newcommand*{\shoe}{\ensuremath{\supset}}
  \newcommand*{\nee}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
  \newcommand*{\nein}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\neg}}}
  \newcommand*{\lub}{\ensuremath{\lor}}
  \newcommand*{\lamp}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\&}}}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
      proof tree,
      for tree={math content},
      [, phantom
        [\nee \exists (D^1 \lamp C^1), just=(premise)
          [\nee C^1 f, just=(premise)
            [\nee D^1 f, just=(negated conclusion)
              [\forall \nee (D^1 \lamp C^1), just={(1, QE)}
                [\nee (D^1 f \lamp C^1 f), just={(4, UQ)}
                  [\nee D^1 f, just={(5, \nee \lamp)}
                  ]
                  [\nee C^1 f
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{document}
```

and `tree2.tex` contains:

```
  \documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi]{standalone}
  \usepackage{prooftrees}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{mathtools,turnstile}
  \newcommand*{\tnot}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
      proof tree,
      [{$(\exists x)(\forall y)(Py \equiv x = y) \vdash (\exists x)((\forall y)(Py \supset x = y) \,\&\, Px)$}
        [{$(\exists x)(\forall y)(Py \equiv x = y)\ \checkmark a$}, just={Premise}
          [{$\tnot (\exists x)((\forall y)(Py \supset x = y) \,\&\, Px)\ \backslash a$}, just={Conclusion negated}
            [{$(\forall y)(Py \equiv a = y)\ \backslash a,b$}, just={From 1}
              [{$\tnot ((\forall y)(Py \supset a = y) \,\&\, Pa)\ \checkmark$}, just={From 2}
                [{$Pa \equiv a = a\ \checkmark$}, just={From 3}
                  [{$Pa$}, just={From 5}
                    [{$a = a$}, just={From 5}
                      [{$\tnot (\forall y)(Py \supset a = y)\ \checkmark b$}, just={From 4}
                        [{$\tnot (Pb \supset a = b)\ \checkmark$}, just={From 8}
                          [{$Pb$}, just={From 9}
                            [{$a \neq b$}, just={From 9}
                              [{$Pb \equiv a = b\ \checkmark$}, just={From 3}
                                [{$Pb$}, just={From 12}
                                  [{$a = b$}, just={From 12}
                                    [{$a \neq a$}, just={From 11,14}, close
                                    ]
                                  ]
                                ]
                                [{$\tnot Pb$}
                                  [{$a \neq b$}, close
                                  ]
                                ]
                              ]
                            ]
                          ]
                        ]
                      ]
                      [{$\tnot Pa$}, close
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                  [{$\tnot Pa$}
                    [{$a \neq a$}, close
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  \end{document}
```

Then we can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{prooftrees,standalone,kantlipsum}
\newcommand*{\shoe}{\ensuremath{\supset}}
\newcommand*{\nee}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
\newcommand*{\nein}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\neg}}}
\newcommand*{\lub}{\ensuremath{\lor}}
\newcommand*{\lamp}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\&}}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,turnstile}
\newcommand*{\tnot}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\sim}}}
\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\kant[1]

This proof is best illustrated by the following tree which is simply typeset:

\begin{center}
  \emph{here}\par
  \input{tree1}
\end{center}

\kant[2-3]

It is time for another tree.
See figure \ref{fig:tree2} (which is \emph{there} and \emph{not} here) for details of this problem and its solution.
\begin{figure}
  \input{tree2}
  \caption{A tree}
  \label{fig:tree2}
\end{figure}

\kant[3]

\end{document}
```

to create the following article:

[image: article creation]